# Excel VBA Run-time error -2147221040 when using Shape.Copy

Tags: excel, vba

I am experimenting with some code found here (https://analystcave.com/excel-image-vba-save-range-workbook-image/) that takes a selected range, copy/pastes as a picture, copy pastes the picture as a chart, copy/pastes the chart area as a picture and saves it as a JPG. Code here:

```
Sub SelectedRangeToImage()

    Dim tmpChart As Chart, n As Long, shCount As Long, sht As Worksheet, sh As Shape

    Dim fileSaveName As Variant, pic As Variant

    'Create temporary chart as canvas

    Set sht = Selection.Worksheet

    Selection.Copy

    sht.Pictures.Paste.Select

    Set sh = sht.Shapes(sht.Shapes.Count)

    Set tmpChart = Charts.Add

    tmpChart.ChartArea.Clear

    tmpChart.Name = "PicChart" & (Rnd() * 10000)

    Set tmpChart = tmpChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=sht.Name)

    tmpChart.ChartArea.Width = sh.Width

    tmpChart.ChartArea.Height = sh.Height

    tmpChart.Parent.Border.LineStyle = 0

    'Paste range as image to chart

    sh.Copy

    tmpChart.ChartArea.Select

    tmpChart.Paste

    'Save chart image to file

    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Image (*.jpg), *.jpg")

    If fileSaveName <> False Then

      tmpChart.Export Filename:=fileSaveName, FilterName:="jpg"

    End If

    'Clean up

    sht.Cells(1, 1).Activate

    sht.ChartObjects(sht.ChartObjects.Count).Delete

    sh.Delete

End Sub
```

The code works perfect when I step through it with the debugger, but when I try to just run the entire macro, it pops up the following error at line `sh.Copy`:

> Run-time error ‘-2147221040 (800401d0’):
>
> Method ‘Copy’ of object ‘Shape’ failed

However, if I choose to debug and then either step through or continue to run uninterrupted from there, it will work. What is causing this error when I try to run it, but not when I step through it?

Comment: I ran your code **without any changes**.  It worked perfectly.  **Be sure you have the proper worksheet active and the proper cells Selected** when you run the code.

Comment: The appropriate sheet and cells are selected. As I mentioned, it works when I step through it but not when it just runs. It's like there is something it is stumbling over that it has time to accommodate when I am going through one line at a time. Any ideas why it would do that?

Comment: @SandPiper you posted this back in 2018 - did you come across a solution? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @Dean, unfortunately, I did not. If you find a solution though, I encourage you to share it as an answer. Turns out a lot of people have come looking at this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as this hasn't garnered a response in a few years, and SandPiper suggested I share an answer, I'll share what I did as a work around.

Some context - I previously worked for a business who was using 64 bit Excel 365 and this never occured (including Excel 2019). However, I joined a new company recently and they are using 32 bit Excel 2016 - for specific business reasons. That being said, if you are running the later this solution could work for you, but additionally, you can try the below solution as well, nonetheless.

So why mention the above? The struggle I was encountering with the 32 bit Excel was that the virtual memory allocation that is used by Excel to do such operations of `copy` and `paste` is very limited relative to the 64 bit versions. As such, when using 32 bit Excel it is common for that virtual memory to be utilised and hence, the runtime error that gets thrown.

With this in mind, one of the solutions I came up with was utilising the `Application.Wait` method, which in principle, gives Excel (the application) enough time to catch up with the program and allow it to execute the command. I found that wrapping this in a while loop to give multiple attempts in a production environment was the best way to go. Please see below code - hope this helps others.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SelectedRangeToImage()

    Const maxPasteAttempts As Long = 5
    Dim iPaste As Long
    Dim tmpChart As Chart, n As Long, shCount As Long, sht As Worksheet, sh As Shape
    Dim fileSaveName As Variant, pic As Variant
    
    'Create temporary chart as canvas
    Set sht = Selection.Worksheet
    Selection.Copy
    sht.Pictures.Paste.Select
    
    Set sh = sht.Shapes(sht.Shapes.Count)
    Set tmpChart = Charts.Add
    
    tmpChart.ChartArea.Clear
    tmpChart.Name = "PicChart" & (Rnd() * 10000)
    
    Set tmpChart = tmpChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=sht.Name)
    tmpChart.ChartArea.Width = sh.Width
    tmpChart.ChartArea.Height = sh.Height
    tmpChart.Parent.Border.LineStyle = 0
    
    'Paste range as image to chart
    On Error Resume Next
    While Err.Number <> 0
        Application.Wait Now() + "00:00:01"
        sh.Copy
        tmpChart.ChartArea.Select
        Application.Wait Now() + "00:00:01"
        tmpChart.Paste
        ' handling while loop
        iPaste = iPaste + 1
        If iPaste >= maxPasteAttempts Then
            MsgBox "Failed to paste - please consult developer.", vbCritical, "Fatal error"
            On Error GoTo 0
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Wend
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Save chart image to file
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Image (*.jpg), *.jpg")
    If fileSaveName <> False Then
      tmpChart.Export Filename:=fileSaveName, FilterName:="jpg"
    End If
    
    'Clean up
    sht.Cells(1, 1).Activate
    sht.ChartObjects(sht.ChartObjects.Count).Delete
    sh.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: the only problem with this solution is that the tool will execute too long especially when you have lots of shapes to copy and paste.

Comment: @AyukNayr this is a workaround solution - if you have a better solution please post it, would be very welcomed..

Comment: I do something similar in PowerPoint, using the WinAPI Sleep function to induce a delay on error followed by a call to DoEvents. There's not much increase in execution time because the calls to Sleep and DoEvents only occur on error. I've also built a much more complex solution in the past using WinAPI calls to query the clipboard status but that's extremely complex, messy, and overkill in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, but with copying PowerPoint 365 notes page text into Word 365 on a 64-bit Windows 10 environment. The workaround was to turn off the extended Clipboard History when running my macro. :-(

Settings > System > Clipboard > Clipboard History slide to Off

For reasons beyond my understanding, asking to copy *one* slide's note page copies *every single slide's note page in the whole presentation*. Given how long my notes are, that likely contributed to the problem.